# template showcase plugin for wordpress/joomla

Tags: wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

I would like to create a website showing various templates for sale (both Wordpress and Joomla) - like a demo page that RocketTheme has. I dont mind using either CMS. Is there a plugin on either CMS to get this job done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use roksprocket from Rockettheme in mosaic mode to show them like they do.